# Extract HIVE table's data in a nested List

Tags: python, scala, list, hive

I have a hive table where the data is like below:

[image]

I want to generate the in the below list format.

```
[15,'E11','-3','-3','-3','PKG1',['D1','V1','L1','STD1'],PKG2,['D2','V2','L2','STD2'],'M']
[16,'E11','-3','-3','-3','PKG1',['D7','V7','-3','-3'],PKG2,['D8','V8','-3','-3'],'M']
[17,'E11','D9','V9','-3','PKG3',['D10','V7','-3','-3'],-3,['-3','-3','-3','-3'],'M']
```

Can anyone please suggest how this be achieved?

Comment: Is this a python or a scala question?

Comment: I am as of now trying with Python

Comment: Can you share Hive table schema in `DESCRIBE table_name` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` format? The attached schema contains duplicate column names, so it's probably some kind of struct not just columns.